# Data Connection Wizard Not loading

Tags: sql, excel

When trying to add external data in excel, the data connection wizard does not load properly for some reason.
I select **Data**,> **From Other sources**, >**From Data Connection Wizard**>**My Data source**>**table i want**...

Then I have no options to set parameters, can only click "Finish" without any query set up.
Just Defaults to "Select * FROM XXXXX"..
Anyone have any ideas as to why this would be the case?

I have done this exact same process before, on multiple occasions, with to issue.

Something has changed to make this process not work properly.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I get an option to select the kind of data; and then a dialog.  Maybe you need a repair on your install?

Answer (score 0):

There are big changes going on in the excel data input environment recently and all the process are being remodeled and reworked. I checked my excel 16 and it doesn't even list the option you mention (Data connection Wizard) anymore. I feel a strong push towards Data model which may not suit me or other, but all other connection methods are gradually ceasing to work.

I would guess you perhaps do not have a latest Excel version and so it just happens.

Comment: You have to specifically enable the legacy wizards in later options of Excel in order to see or use them.

Comment: It looks like i can still use them, but they simply don't work properly...